# Angular and FabricJS event handler using local variable

Tags: angular, fabricjs

i am using Angular 5 and FabricJS and i have local variable "iter" and object "circle". I want always as i click on "circle" increase "iter". But I dont have access to variable "iter".

const iter=0;

circle.on("mousedown",function(){iter++;});

Answer (score 0):

You cant change a `const` as they are constant once set. You will need to use `var iter = 0;` or `let iter = 0;` if you wish to change the value.